# Will Ubuntu 11.04 support Apache 2.4?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

I need to upgrade the apache version because the current Apache/2.2.17 is not supporting TLS 1.2
But before going forward I want to know if ubuntu 11.04 support Apache 2.4

PS: This is a live server, I can not update the ubuntu version.

Comment: This is a live server, you should have updated it years ago. Now you have an extremely risky server. NOT updating it will cause you all sorts of grief, not only this instant problem, but others as well. And you can't run TLS 1.2 on it anyway since it's too old. And it's probably been compromised so you'll end up having to build a new server anyway...

Comment: You need to build a replacement server with a supported operating system. Migrate the web site to the new server, make sure everything works. Then switch to the new server and remove the old one completely. You have no other option for a live server that is reachable in the internet. At the same time, you might want to look into automating the server provisioning process, so that you can replace servers easier when needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the official documentation [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), Ubuntu 11.04 has reached end of life in 2012. So no security or other type of updates will be made.
When choosing an Ubuntu version, try to choose one with LTS (Long time support) on it. The current version 20.04 is a LTS version.

Comment: This is a live server, I can not just update the ubuntu version. Thanks

Comment: you will have to compile it manually, doubt you will get working binaries for such an old version. If it is a live server, migration is overdue!

Comment: @ezra-s thank you for your response, could you please check this http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/03/how-to-install-apache-24-from-source.html
will it work for me? I can not take chance to hit ant try.

Comment: It will work since it says in the end of the article. But I do not recomend it. It show how to compile version 2.4.1. This latest version is 2.4.46 and this is the version to use. The apache httpd relies on a number of libraries that are required for it to work - APR and APR-Util for instance - that might not be avaliable and should be also compiled. If you are not familiar with compiling this type of packages the best solution for you is to install a new Ubuntu and use the apache httpd that comes with it.